# T-SQL Pivot by 2 fields and grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to pivot the rows in the attached image and I want the output to look something like this

```
ID   Age   Factor
1    30    8.650
1    35    11.52
1    40    13.87
```

till 100

```
2    30    7.99
2    35    10.98
2    40    13.43

till 100

3    30    7.32
3    35    10.98
3    40    13.43
```

till 100

and so on until i reach the last row (81) in the attached data source.
Thank you :)

Source data

[image]

Comment: that's quite unclear. In your data, the line 2 correspond at the output number 1 etc right ? The name of your columns is F1, F2 etc ? The first column correspond only to the row number ? We have to do a query, but what is the table name ? It's a unpivot and not a pivot you're looking for.

Comment: the output number 1 can be auto generated number. the idea is to output the 1 field 81 times. Yes the name of the fields are F1, F2. If i change the field names, would that help ?

Comment: what thing 'TILL 100'?

Comment: the first field ID as it starts with 1 gets repeated 10 times, then 2 repeated 20 times. The ID field will go upto 81.

Comment: So the first row in your table has the numbers (30-100) and your field names are F1, F2, F3... etc?

Comment: yes, the snapshot is the datasource. This is how i receive the data and I have to pivot it to the output I explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working -

SELECT a.ID - 1 AS ID, b.Age, CAST(b.Factor AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS Factor
from t1 a -- data source table.
cross apply (values
                (30, F1),
                (35, F2),
                (40, F3),
                (45, F4),
                (50, F5),
                (55, F6),
                (60, F7),
                (65, F8),
                (70, F9),
                (100, F10)
                ) b(Age, Factor)
where a.ID >= 2